# How to use React JS component in AEM Adaptive form

Tags: aem

Can someone guide me, how to use React component in AEM Adaptive form, I want the React component to be available in the allowed component list for the adaptive form, so author can drag and drop the component to add it into the adaptive form.

I have tried the tutorial from below link to add React JS component in AEM sites page, I am able to drag and drop the AEM custom component(custom component has the reference of React component) available in the allowed components list to add the component into the sites page. But the same approach is not working for AEM Adaptive forms.

Tutorial link: https://blogs.perficient.com/2019/09/17/creating-your-first-custom-aem-component-using-react-part-1/

This tutorial is using '@adobe/cq-react-editable-components' and '@adobe/cq-spa-page-model-manager'. These 2 libraries are for Sites only.